# How can I rotate the game stage?

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a pseudo-game which I'm developing in 9:16, to be displayed in vertical screens. The client now needs another version in 16:9, rotated in 90º.

I tried creating a empty object, putting all my elements inside it, and rotating, but it caused a lot of positioning bugs, probably because of *localPosition vs position*.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is **what in have** vs **what I need**:

[image: portrait and landscape displays]

Comment: Desktop or mobile?

Comment: @Evorlor, Desktop

Comment: Then your approach should work.  Make sure you are moving everything with a null parent to be parented by your new GameObject.  Make sure the GameObject's position is (0, 0, 0).  Then rotate it by 90 degrees.  Check to be sure you are not changing the parenting of the children afterwards.

Comment: Why not just rotate the camera?

Comment: you can rotate camera or just set screen.orientation

Comment: @virtouso want to make that comment into an answer we can upvote to stop this old question from being repeatedly bumped?

Comment: @DMGregory sure. please write that asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider to leave the scene as it is and simply rotate the camera by 90°?

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping between the position in the vertical screen to that in the horizontal one, so that you reposition all elements according to this mathematical mapping.
i.e. : loop through all elements and apply  the mapping to each one.